# struts tags in jsp for setting correct property

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

while using this I'm unable to make use of the property tag it prints the #rowstatus.index but I need it to not show as a label

```
<s:property id="domainName_" value="#rowstatus.index"/><s:property value="domainName" />
```

"11"ENTITY_TYPE

this if statement give me the correct property

```
<s:if test="%{#request.documentationLink != null}">
<a href="<s:property value="#request.documentationLink"/>"target="_blank"
id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property value="domainName" /></a>
</s:if>
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
<span id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>">
  <s:property value="domainName" />
</span>
```

used span instead